# Unable to add myself to the docker group

Tags: ubuntu, users, group

I confirmed that the `docker` group exists

```
$ grep -i docker /etc/group
docker:x:130:
```

but when i tried `usermod -aG docker`, I got the usage output

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
  -G, --groups GROUPS           new list of supplementary GROUPS
  -a, --append                  append the user to the supplemental GROUPS
                                mentioned by the -G option without removing
                                him/her from other groups
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -l, --login NEW_LOGIN         new value of the login name
  -L, --lock                    lock the user account
  -m, --move-home               move contents of the home directory to the
                                new location (use only with -d)
  -o, --non-unique              allow using duplicate (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       use encrypted password for the new password
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -s, --shell SHELL             new login shell for the user account
  -u, --uid UID                 new UID for the user account
  -U, --unlock                  unlock the user account
  -v, --add-subuids FIRST-LAST  add range of subordinate uids
  -V, --del-subuids FIRST-LAST  remove range of subordinate uids
  -w, --add-subgids FIRST-LAST  add range of subordinate gids
  -W, --del-subgids FIRST-LAST  remove range of subordinate gids
  -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     new SELinux user mapping for the user account
```

When I used `id` to check, I am not part of the `docker` group.

What have I missed?

OS: ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You appear to have missed the `LOGIN` i.e. the name of the user who you want to add to the group

Comment: OMG, it is so obvious! I was expecting (wrongly) it will pickup my userid as default. Please make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 7):

### Required parameter missing

Perhaps you'll need to **specify `LOGIN`, a required parameter** seen in the *‘Usage:’* message.

---

#### tl;dr

- **`usermod -a -G docker <your username>`**

*see also:*

- **`gpasswd -a <your username> docker`**

---

*Don't forget to login again or use `newgrp docker` to make sure this takes effect.*

Comment: Wow, always wondering how to apply changes without relogin/restarting. `newgrp docker` rules.

Comment: newgrp docker is very different from usermod -aG: newgrp changes primary group ID where usermod -aG does not, it adds user to the group so it can access files owned by that group.